# FileNotFound: Apache Beam FileIO with spaces in GCS filename

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, file-io, apache-beam

I am using an apache beam pipeline in java for loading files into BigQuery.

```
class explodeFileBytes extends DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, KV<ArrayList<String>,String>> implements Serializable {
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    try (BufferedReader = new 
    BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(c.element().open(),"ISO_8859_1"))) {
    Integer lineNr = 1;
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        ArrayList<String> fileMetaDataArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fileName,lineNr.toString()));
        KV<ArrayList<String>,String> rowObject = KV.of(fileMetaDataArray,line);
        c.output(rowObject);
        line = br.readLine();
        lineNr++;
    }
}
    catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}


PCollection<KV<ArrayList<String>,String>> rowsAndContents = pipeline
    .apply(FileIO.match(),filepattern("gs://mybucket/mydirectory/**"))
    .apply(FileIO.readMatches()
    .apply(ParDo.of(new explodeFileBytes()));
```

If the file has a space in the name, I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException when attempting to load it using FileIO. For sure the file exists and it is looking for the right file.  We are sure it is a problem in the FileIO class.

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Comment: Have you tested it with a file without spaces in the name? This should not be a problem

Comment: Yes.  It works fine with files that have no spaces.  The only exceptions that are printed are files with spaces.

Comment: Are you using the last version of beam?

Comment: Yes.  I guess the question is if someone can either replicate the problem or not.  On our machines, we are consistently getting this error.

Comment: @TannerClark have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Nope.  Extremely frustrating.  The work around is copying with new names and then feeding into beam